# Does a Psychic Caster still have to point to cast Mage Hand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

[Psychic Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/psychic-magic) says that Psychic Casters (from Occult Adventures) use emotional and thought components rather than verbal and somatic components:

> Instead of verbal and somatic components, all psychic spells have components related to the caster's inner being. The two psychic components are called emotion components and thought components. If a spell's components line lists a somatic component, that spell instead requires an emotion component when cast by psychic spellcasters, and if it has a verbal component, it instead requires a thought component when cast by psychic spellcasters.

However, [*mage hand*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-hand) (and all other spells that include an action in their casting), says

> You point your finger at an object and can lift it and move it at will from a distance.

As I understand it, the Verbal and Somatic components are the "Words of Power" and arcane hand signs used to actually cast the spell. Once it's cast you still need to make it work (Sort of like holding the charge on a touch spell.) Am I wrong here?

Comment: There's some interesting overlap with [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46603/8610), although this is certainly *not* a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Psychic Spellcasting removes the need for somatic components, but the "point your finger" line isn't actually a somatic component, it's a description of what the spell lets you do.

Basically, you cast the spell (which requires somatic/verbal or emotion/thought components), and then point at the thing you want to move.  Pointing is part of the *effect* of the spell, not the *cost*, to put it another way.

It works the same way for [Still Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/still-spell-metamagic---final).  The feat removes somatic components, but it doesn't remove the need to point at the object you want to move.  You can try to hide the fact that you're pointing (probably with a sleight of hand check), but the movement is non-optional.