# Can a Light Domain Cleric cast Burning Hands while carrying a shield?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, shield

I have a Light Domain Cleric who gets, as part of the Light Domain, the Burning Hands spell. Can I cast this spell while carrying a shield?

I subscribe to the idea that [one physically must touch one's thumbs together and spread one's fingers per the spell as the somatic component of the spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46603/does-burning-hands-really-require-touching-thumbs). Is it reasonable to think that a Cleric with a shield strapped to their arm is able to make such a gesture and not burn their own shield?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If a spell requires a somatic component, the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures. [PHB, pg. 203]

You do not have free use of a hand if that hand is holding a shield.  [If you rule that *Burning Hands* requires free use of two hands to perform its somatic component](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46603/does-burning-hands-really-require-touching-thumbs), then by default you cannot cast it while also holding a shield.

The *War Caster* feat, of course, allows casting while holding weapons and/or a shield.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually an answer from Jeremy Crawford that might answer this question.

> **can a Cleric or Paladin cast spells requiring somatic components when
> wielding weapon + shield emblazoned with holy symbol?**
>
> I'd say yes if the holy symbol is being used as the material component of the spell,
> so yes if "S, M," but no if only "S." -J

Since the Burning Hands spell does not require a material, the shield cannot be used as the somatic component.