# Does Shadow Lore require the Bard to physically whisper, and could the target or a nearby creature detect this?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, hearing

A 14th level College of Whispers Bard gains the following class feature:

> **Shadow Lore**: As an action, you magically whisper a phrase that only one creature of your choice within 30 feet of you can hear. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw against your spell save DC. It automatically succeeds if it doesn’t share a language with you or if it can’t hear you. On a successful saving throw, your whisper sounds like unintelligible mumbling and has no effect.
>
> If the target fails its saving throw, it is charmed by you for the next 8 hours or until you or your allies attack or damage it. It interprets the whispers as a description of its most mortifying secret.
>
> While you gain no knowledge of this secret, the target is convinced you know it. While charmed in this way, the creature obeys your commands for fear that you will reveal its secret. It won’t risk its life for you or fight for you, unless it was already inclined to do so. It grants you favors and gifts it would offer to a close friend.
>
> When the effect ends, the creature has no understanding of why it held you in such fear.
>
> *(pg 16, Xanathar's Guide to Everything)*

When using Shadow Lore, would the Bard physically whisper something that only the Target can hear, or is it more like a telepathic whisper that the target hears?

Would the target, or a nearby creature, be able to tell that Shadow Lore was used and potentially who used it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You do have to actually whisper, but nobody else will hear you; what others creatures notice would be up to a GM

The feature states:

> As an action, you magically whisper a phrase that **only one creature of your choice within 30 feet of you can hear**...

This is a result of spells and features not having any sort of "fluff" text in fifth edition. This is discussed at length in the answer to the question: "[Does Burning Hands really require touching thumbs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46603)".

This text states that you do whisper the phrase however only one creature hears it and it is a creature of your choice within 30 feet of you.

All we know is that the spell is a magical whisper which nobody else can hear. The general English meaning of the word "whisper" would certainly point to it requiring you to actually speak, and thus move your mouth which would be visually noticeable, though inaudible.
What knowledge a creature may gain from seeing your lips move, if anything, is left up to a GM.

Similarly, even if a creature could read lips, this would be left up to the GM. Perhaps your lips don't even move in normal shapes and ways; after all, on a successful save "your whisper sounds like unintelligible mumbling", quite different from what it *should* sound like. So whether it also can *look* different would be up to your GM.

Comment: So it could be possible for a bystander to see you whisper, they just wouldn't hear anything?

Comment: @mullac I've edited the last paragraph a bit, in the end you'd have to ask your GM what, if anything, a creature learns if they see your lips moving.

Comment: @Medix2 could you address if a creature that can read lips (Perceptive? Feat) could understand the whisper.

Comment: @daleM I would say that's up to a GM, technically, linguistically your lips move differently when you whisper so a GM would have to decide how that works out

Comment: @mullac If you don't want them seeing, you could cover your face.

Comment: @MarkWells That has a good chance of ruining the effect, though, since the target needs to hear you.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Isn't the sound conveyed to the target by magic? _You_ can't hear what it's actually saying to them.

Comment: @markwells yes, this is especially clear as it's a whisper being heard by somebody 30 feet away

Comment: @MarkWells "It automatically succeeds if it doesn’t share a language with you or if it can’t hear you"

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Right, I notice that now, and it's even more confusing--how are they supposed to hear a whisper at 30 feet? The only sensible interpretation I can come up with is that this means "if it can't _hear_", that is, the spell can't whisper in their ear if they don't have any ears.

Comment: @MarkWells Or you could just be closer.  Or whisper shout.  Or use a megaphone. Or have a very perceptive target.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I think it would be rather absurd if the spell requires you to still whisper *magically* and still have the whisper be loud enough for somebody 30 feet away to hear you. Although, in the end, it doesn't matter, if that's the requirement then it's the requirement but the only person who can understand it is the target, so nothing has changed, it seems like that's a more "up to your GM" thing if anything at all. The logistics of the whisper aren't explained

Comment: @Medix2 We are agreed on that.