# Can the Mage Hand Spell do somatic components if the person who cast it doesn't have a free hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, spell-components

A wizard casts the [Mage Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) spell. They then pick up a short sword and a shield. They then want to cast Burning Hands against an opponent. Can they use the active Mage Hand to provide the somatic component for it?

Comment: I believe the roll20 spell descriptions and such sometimes get things wrong, subtle things like capitalisation. I've swapped that our for an inline D&DBeyond link, which seems to be RPG.SE's favoured online resource for 5e.

Comment: Actually, you use *both* hands when casting Burning Hands — https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46603/

Answer (score 22):

### **No.**

*Mage Hand* is a spell, whose effect reminds of a hand but with severely limited capabilities compared to a real hand. Imagine it, as it is depicted in many illustrations, more like a semi-translucent shape of magical force.

The spell description lists the exact range of actions that can be undertaken through it. Some class specialization (like Trickster Rogue) have access to extra actions but nowhere it's listed that you can use it to provide a somatic component for further spellcasting. Because it's not an action.

Casting a spell with somatic components require gestures and possibly handling of a material component. This must be done with a free hand (gloves don't count) or while handling the material component in the hand. By the rules you can't delegate this part of spellcasting to a minion, a familiar, a friend, an *invisible servitor* or any spell effect.

Comment: Hi Kotrin, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more guidance. This is a good first answer, +1 from me!

Answer (score -2):

RAW, no. Would I allow it, yes. What I would say though, is that you have to maintain concentration on it of course, but you have to succeed on a wisdom check of 10 + two times the spells level. If you have benefits to maintaining concentration from abilities such as the warcaster feat, you gain them on this check. Also, remember that it costs an action to summon the hand. As well as this, you would loose the ability to cast spells that require concentration, so I would say that its balanced.

Comment: That's a whole lot of houserules for this. Have you actually tried it and can talk about how it went? It seems pretty complicated and adds new mechanics that the player and DM have to track.

Comment: Mage Hand isn't a concentration spell. Are you saying you'd add a concentration requirement when using it this way? That's an awkward fit with the rules, because a spell generally requires you to concentrate for its whole duration, not just for one turn.

Comment: @MarkWells My interpretation is that *mage hand* doesn't require concentration, but that if you use your *mage hand* for somatic components, it can't be for a concentration spell.